# Remove element with attribute JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, attributes

I want to remove element with `data-loc-id='2218'`. How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
document.querySelectorAll(`[data-loc-id='2218']`).remove();
```

Error: `Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).remove is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelectorAll()` returns collection, you should loop through them and remove one by one:

```
document.querySelectorAll(`[data-loc-id='2218']`).forEach(el => el.remove());
```

**OR:** If you have single element with the attribute value then use `querySelector()` which returns the first matched element in the document:

```
document.querySelector(`[data-loc-id='2218']`).remove();
```

Comment: How about a close vote instead of just another _"... returns a collection"_ answer?